# Implementing metatags for open graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Facebook needs the url of the object when sending a action post request. Now , my app only allows authorized users, I redirect the user to the login page and it redirects back to the user requested page.

But how do I differentiate between fb trying to access the metatags(while posting) or users coming from fb whom I have to redirect ?

Comment: Did you ever get to solve this. I'm running into a similar issue. That I am not able to redirect the user to my page instead it goes to the action page (with metadata) and stays there.

Answer (score 2):

You missed some concepts behind of OpenGraph. All objects should have a publicly accessible representing page.

Citing [Publishing Objects](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/#publish) section from [Facebook's OpenGraph Objects](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/) documentation:

> Open Graph Objects are simply your web pages with Open Graph meta tags. Before you can publish an Open Graph object, you must define its corresponding object type in the Open Graph section of the Developer App. Once you have defined your object type in the tool, you **must create a publicly accessible web page that represents your object** using Open Graph metatags. We provide boilerplate metatags that you can use to create this web page in the Developer App (click the Get Code link next to your object definition). With these tags in place, you can publish actions that refer to your object.
>
> When Facebook sees the first action applied to your object, **we will scrape your page, read its meta tags and connect the user to your object**, via the action. Every 7 days after the initial scrape of your object, **we will attempt to re-scrape your object** to keep the object data up to date.

Comment: Alright. So I make a publicly accessible page , basically just metatags which I change according to each object. But I need to provide an og:url in that, pointing toward the orignal object page. So ,facebook should post the action with url pointed by og:url, correct? Eg- iamkhush is reading an article(pointing to og:url). Here, og:url points to the app url, which requires the authorization first, so the user will be redirected to auth page first, if unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was to differentiate between a Facebook crawler and a user.

I don't remember the exact thing I wrote, but the general idea was that facebook parser just reads the html head tags . I added a fb redirect which sends the authenticated user to the desired page . This redirect wouldnt affect the crawler because javascript isnt executed by a crawler.

Now , since my need was to allow only authenticated users to go ahead, the FB js api handled auth as well. :)

Do tell me , if you need to know the specific fb api call.